# Does Gorm automatically close the connection?

Tags: go, aws-lambda, go-gorm

I have been using GORM for my application based on AWS lambda. I used gorm.Open() for every Handler function,

```
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })
```

so can someone help me confirm that does gorm.Open(...) automatically close the connection or not? Or I must use generic database interface bellow?

```
// Get generic database object sql.DB to use its functions
sqlDB, err := db.DB()

// Ping
sqlDB.Ping()

// Close
sqlDB.Close()

// Returns database statistics
sqlDB.Stats()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `gorm.DB` object is intended to be reused, like a `sql.DB` handle. You rarely have to explicitly close these objects. Just create it once and reuse it.

`gorm.DB` contains a [`sql.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB) which uses a connection pool to manage the connections. If it is closed, it will stop accepting new queries, wait for running queries to finish and close all connections.